# Facebook API errors with "Session key invalid or no longer valid"

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

Doing some work with Facebook connect/the RESTful API and for some reason i keep getting this error

```
Session key invalid or no longer valid
```

As far as i can tell im authenticating correctly. Getting the session key from the cookie after the facebook connect dialog pops up and the user logs in.
Then i open up the extended permissions dialog to allow posting events and offline access.

But then if the user was to logout of facebook the session key becomes unusable. What am i doing wrong here? Is there any good examples of doing this with ASP.NET/C#?

Comment: The session key is valid only for that user's session. So, when they log out the session is closed.

The correct approach is as below by obtaining an API key for your application.

Comment: My application has an API key and for each of the user sessions they grant my application offline access so i should be able to post even after they log out. It seems to be working now tho... so no idea...

Answer (score 1):

I use [Facebook Dev Toolkit v3.0](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com) and have mananged to get it to work. Give that a try. My code does this to the client.

Redirect the browser to:

```
url = @"http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=" + _fbService.Session.ApplicationKey + @"&v=1.0" + @"&next=" + fullReturnUrl + "?";
```

Then for extended permissions

```
url = @"http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_permissions.php?api_key=" + _fbService.Session.ApplicationKey + @"&v=1.0&next=" + fullReturnUrl + "?xxRESULTTOKENxx" + @"&display=popup&" + @"&ext_perm=offline_access,publish_stream,read_stream" + @"&enable_profile_selector=1";
```

Once that comes back successfully, its simply a matter of storing the auth_token

```
string authToken = webContext.Request["auth_token"];
```

With the extended permissions, I am able to get access even though the person has logged off Facebook.

Comment: @Tom, which code are you talking about? From Facebook or from the web app?